# Squares that cannot be shown as sum of squares

Tags: square-numbers

How many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are there so that there exists no such $M \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n^2 =\sum_{i=0}^{M}{a_i^2}$ for distinct $a_i \in  \mathbb{N}$?

Source: http://mishabucko.wordpress.com

Comment: Can you be more specific about the source? I don't see anything on that page that mentions squares anywhere (and unfortunately quite a bit of babble).

Comment: Sure, http://mishabucko.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/distinct-square-representation-problem/

Answer (score 3):

Halter-Koch [HK] showed that the largest *integer* not expressible as a sum of $5$ distinct non-zero squares with greater common divisor $1$ is $N^{*}(5)=245$.  You can check the fifteen distinct squares $\le 15^2=225$ by hand.  I find that

- $5^2 = 3^2 + 4^2$
- $7^2 = 2^2 + 3^2 + 6^2$
- $9^2 = 2^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2$
- $10^2 = 6^2 + 8^2$
- $11^2 = 2^2 + 6^2 + 9^2$
- $13^2 = 3^2 + 4^2 + 12^2$
- $14^2 = 4^2 + 6^2 + 12^2$
- $15^2 = 9^2 + 12^2.$

So unless I'm missing one, the only squares not expressible as sums of distinct squares are these seven: $\{1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,6^2,8^2,12^2\}$.

[HK] F. Halter-Koch, Darstellung naturlicher Zahlen als Summe von Quadraten, Acta Arith. 42 (1982), 11–20.

Comment: That is a handy theorem of Halter-Koch, nice mjq!

Comment: Bateman, Hildebrand, & Purdy show that the gcd condition can be dropped: $N*(k)=N(k)$ for $k\ge5.$